# flink how to guarantee exactly once for kafka records despite retries

Tags: apache-flink

My source and sink are both Kafka topics. Is there a way to generate an unique id exact once for each distinct Kafka record? Exact once means if retry happens, the same record still use the same previously generated id, and the sink only exists single record.

Comment: I'm not sure what you requirements are exactly. This might help you: https://www.callicoder.com/distributed-unique-id-sequence-number-generator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you hoping to gain by adding this unique id, nor are the requirements for its uniqueness entirely clear.

But if your concern is that Flink will create duplicate records in the output topic because of retries that occur during failure recovery, you can configure Flink and Kafka to avoid this, and have guaranteed exactly-once behavior.

To achieve exactly-once end-to-end guarantees:

- Enable Flink checkpointing
- Set `Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE`
- Increase the `transaction.max.timeout.ms` beyond the default (15 minutes)
- Set the `isolation.level` in downstream consumers to `read_committed`

This approach does come at the price of the downstream Kafka consumers having an expected latency equal to the checkpointing interval.

See [the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-011-and-newer) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest idea that comes into mind is to simply create a function that generates unique `hashcode()` for each record as `long`. If the hashcode will be based on fields then it will be the same for non-distinct records and should be different for distinct ones.

You can even consider using the `hashcode()` from `Object` in Java.